# Race condition appending to mutable Map in future

Tags: scala

I need to append to a `Map` structure from within a future, and I couldn't find a way to make the `Map` immutable (See below). I'm afraid that if the `Map` is mutable then I will have a race condition. How to fix the code below?

```
object TestFutures extends App {

  val m = collection.mutable.Map[Int,String]()

  val f0 = Future { 0 }
  val f1 = Future { 1 }
  val f2 = Future { 2 }
  val f3 = Future { 3 }
  val f4 = Future { 4 }

  val fx = Seq(f0,f1,f2,f3,f4)

  fx.map {
     i => 
       i.map {
         x =>
           val s = x + ""
           m += ( x -> s )
     }
  }

  Thread.sleep(5000)
  println(m)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way to get the result as an immutable `Map`.

```
val fx = Future.sequence(Seq(f0,f1,f2,f3,f4))
               .map(_.map(i => i -> s"$i").toMap)
//fx: Future[scala.collection.immutable.Map[Int,String]]
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you should use `mutable map` for this, because you can't know when these futures are done. you only can do by checking the `map`'s size to check whether match the **futures** size, but if there is a key is override, you never know when the **futures** is finished.

So I think you can convert `Seq[Future[Int]]` of `fx` to `Future[Seq[Int]]` and `map` it to `Future[Map[Int, String]]`, so you can know when these futures is done and do some other thing, like:

```
val res: Future[Map[Int, String]] = Future.sequence(fx).map(s => s.map(i => (i, i.toString)).toMap) // this will generate a immutable variable
val r: Map[Int, String] = Await.wait(res, Duration.Inf) //!!! Await just for test purpose
```